# How to know what are the prerequisites for my windows form application

Tags: c#, .net, installshield, windows

I have made an application using C# in windows forms. I am using Install shield 2010 to create a setup file for the application. It asks me what it should check for as prerequisites which it would check for before starting to install on any other device.

However, I do not know what I should include as prerequisites for my windows application. I do not know if it requires .net 4.5 or 4 or 3.5... I also had downloaded and included some references in the project and do not know if they are being included in the setup or not...

Please help

Comment: I am using visual studio 2013 for the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the project properties of your winform app and see what version of the .NET framework you are building against.  In some cases you can do things like compile against .NET 2.0 but then have an App.Config file that says 2.0 and 4.0 are supported runtimes.  This gives you flexibility in choosing which if any .NET to redistribute.

From there you have to look at your dependencies (references)  and there dependencies.   It's possible that they require additional things such as C++ runtimes,  database engines.   For each of these you have to figure out if it's already part of windows,  if a third party redistributable exists, can it be statically linked or privately deployed and so on.

There is no one simple answer.  You just have to be familiar with your code base, what it requires and what the best practices are for each of those items.